# AWK print block that does NOT contain specific text

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following data file:

```
variable "ARM_CLIENT_ID" {
  description = "Client ID for Service Principal"
}

variable "ARM_CLIENT_SECRET" {
  description = "Client Secret for Service Principal"
}

# [.....loads of code]

variable "logging_settings" {
  description = "Logging settings from TFVARs"
}

variable "azure_firewall_nat_rule_collections" {
  default = {}
}

variable "azure_firewall_network_rule_collections" {
  default = {}
}

variable "azure_firewall_application_rule_collections" {
  default = {}
}

variable "build_route_tables" {
  description = "List of Route Table keys that need direct internet prior to Egress FW build"
  default = [
    "shared_services",
    "sub_to_afw"
  ]
}
```

There's a 2 things I wish to do:

- print the variable names without the inverted commas
- ONLY print the variables names if the code block does NOT contain `default`

I know I can print the variables names like so: `awk '{ gsub("\"", "") }; (/variable/ && $2 !~ /^ARM_/) { print $2}'`

I know I can print the code blocks with: `awk '/variable/,/^}/'`, which results:

```
# [.....loads of code output before this]

variable "logging_settings" {
  description = "Logging settings from TFVARs"
}
variable "azure_firewall_nat_rule_collections" {
  default = {}
}
variable "azure_firewall_network_rule_collections" {
  default = {}
}
variable "azure_firewall_application_rule_collections" {
  default = {}
}
variable "build_route_tables" {
  description = "List of Route Table keys that need direct internet prior to Egress FW build"
  default = [
    "shared_services",
    "sub_to_afw"
  ]
}
```

However, I cannot find out how to print the code blocks "if" they don't contain `default`. I know I will need to use an `if` statement, and some variables perhaps, but I am unsure as of how.

This code block should NOT appear in the output for which I grab the variable name:

```
variable "build_route_tables" {
  description = "List of Route Table keys that need direct internet prior to Egress FW build"
  default = [
    "shared_services",
    "sub_to_afw"
  ]
}
```

End output should NOT contain those that had `default`:

```
# [.....loads of code output before this]
expressroute_settings
firewall_settings
global_settings
peering_settings
vnet_transit_object
vnet_shared_services_object
route_tables
logging_settings
```

Preferable I would like to keep this a single AWK command or file, no piping. I have uses for this that do prefer no piping.

**EDIT**: update the ideal outputs (missed some examples of those with `default`)

Comment: Why is `azure_firewall_application_rule_collections` in the output? The code block has `default = {}`

Comment: The condition `!/regexp/` will be true if the record doesn't match the regexp.

Comment: @Barmar; Ok, how do I use that to eliminate the block I do not want?

Comment: If you only print the blocks that satisfy that condition, you'll eliminate the other blocks.

Comment: please update the expected output to match the sample input (eg, `expressroute_settings` is not in the sample input but is in the expected output ... ??

Comment: No @markp-fuso, it is not, but as you can see at the top of that list I have made a comment that it includes a lot of code output before it. basically, i truncated a load of useless text

Comment: @Barmar; that's exactly what i'm asking. How do i print just those blocks that DON'T include `default` within them? I have no idea.

Comment: Nothing is printed by default. So if you use `!/default =/` as your condition, it will only print those blocks.

Comment: @Barmar; can you please write out the command/formula so I can fully understand how you intend it to be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions and collection of notes from OP's question and comments:

- all variable definition blocks end with a right brace (`}`) in the first column of a new line
- we only display `variable` names (sans the double quotes)
- we do not display the `variable` names if the body of the variable definition contains the string `default`
- we do not display the `variable` name if it starts with the string `ARM_`

One (somewhat verbose) `awk` solution:

**NOTE**: I've copied the sample input data into my local file `variables.dat`

```
awk -F'"' '                                              # use double quotes as the input field separator
/^variable / && $2 !~ "^ARM_"  { varname = $2            # if line starts with "^variable ", and field #2 is not like "^ARM_", save field #2 for later display
                                 printme = 1             # enable our print flag
                               }
/variable/,/^}/                { if ( $0 ~ "default" )   # within the range of a variable definition, if we find the string "default" ...
                                    printme = 0          # disable the print flag
                                 next                    # skip to next line
                               }
printme                        { print varname           # if the print flag is enabled then print the variable name and then ...
                                 printme = 0             # disable the print flag
                               }
' variables.dat
```

This generates:

```
logging_settings
```

Comment: forgot to say "thank you" last night, this helped a lot and has given me more insight into awk functionality

Answer (score 1):

Another variation on `awk` using `skip` variable to control the array index holding the variable names:

```
awk '
    /^[[:blank:]]*#/ { next }
    $1=="variable"   { gsub(/["]/,"",$2); vars[skip?n:++n]=$2; skip=0 } 
    $1=="default"    { skip=1 }
    END { if (skip) n--; for(i=1; i<=n; i++) print vars[i] }
' code
```

The first rule just skips comment lines. If you want to skip `"ARM_"` variables, then you can add a test on `$2`.

**Example Use/Output**

With your example code in `code`, all variables without `default` are:

```
$ awk '
>     /^[[:blank:]]*#/ { next }
>     $1=="variable"   { gsub(/["]/,"",$2); vars[skip?n:++n]=$2; skip=0 }
>     $1=="default"    { skip=1 }
>     END { if (skip) n--; for(i=1; i<=n; i++) print vars[i] }
> ' code
ARM_CLIENT_ID
ARM_CLIENT_SECRET
logging_settings
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk:

```
awk -v RS="}" '/variable/ && !/default/ && !/ARN/ { var=gensub(/(^.*variable ")(.*)(".*{.*)/,"\\2",$0);print var }' file
```

Set the record separator to "}" and then check for records that contain "variable", don't contain default and don't contain "ARM". Use gensub to split the string into three sections based on regular expressions and set the variable var to the second section. Print the var variable.

Output:

```
logging_settings
```

Comment: The last 3 lines shouldn't be in the output, since they have `default`.

Comment: I don't think he wants ARM entries either so it's just logging_settings

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v RS= '!/default =/{gsub(/"/,"",$2); print $2}' file

ARM_CLIENT_ID
ARM_CLIENT_SECRET
[.....loads
logging_settings
```

of course output doesn't match yours since it's inconsistent with the input data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another maybe shorter solution.

```
$ awk -F'"' '/^variable/&&$2!~/^ARM_/{v=$2} /default =/{v=0} /}/&&v{print v; v=0}' file
logging_settings
```