# AWK create internal variable array from results and print in END block

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following `variables.tf` file:

```
variable "ARM_CLIENT_ID" {
  description = "Client ID for Service Principal"
}

variable "ARM_CLIENT_SECRET" {
  description = "Client Secret for Service Principal"
}

variable "ARM_ENVIRONMENT" {
  description = "The deployment environment acronym to which the resources are being deployed"
}

variable "ARM_LOCATION" {
  description = "The geo location to which the resources are being deployed"
}

variable "ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID" {
  description = "Azure Subscription for deployment"
}

variable "ARM_TENANT_ID" {
  description = "Azure AD tenant identifier for Service Principal"
}

variable "expressroute_settings" {
  description = "(Required) ExpressRoute Gateway and Public IP settings"
}

variable "firewall_settings" {
  description = "(Required) ExpressRoute Gateway and Public IP settings"
}

variable "global_settings" {
  description = "Global settings for subscription"
}

variable "peering_settings" {
  description = "(Required) vNet Peering configuration for shared services vnets"
}

variable "vnet_transit_object" {
  description = "(Required) configuration object describing the transit networking configuration, as described in README"
}

variable "vnet_shared_services_object" {
  description = "(Required) configuration object describing the shared services networking configuration, as described in README"
}

variable "route_tables" {
  description = "Routes for subnets declared in tfvars"
}

variable "logging_settings" {
  description = "Logging settings from TFVARs"
}

variable "azure_firewall_nat_rule_collections" {
  default = {}
}

variable "azure_firewall_network_rule_collections" {
  default = {}
}

variable "azure_firewall_application_rule_collections" {
  default = {}
}
```

With the help of [AWK print block that does NOT contain specific text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65258013/awk-print-block-that-does-not-contain-specific-text) I was able to come up with the following AWK program that helps me print out the results as long as they don't contain the word `default` in the block.

```
BEGIN   {
    string = "route_tables,global_settings"
    regex = "[,]"
    n = split ( string, arr, regex )
}
{ gsub("\"", "") }
/^variable/     {   varname = $2
                    printme = 1
                }
                {
                    for ( i=1; i<=n; i++ )
                        if ( $2 ~ arr[i] )
                            printme = 0
                            myarr[i] = $2
                }
/variable/,/^}/ {   if ( $0 ~ "default" )
                        printme = 0
                    next
                }
printme         {   printf varname " = \"\"\n"
                    printme = 0
                }
END {
    for ( x=1; x<=n; x++ )
        print myarr[x]
}
```

Which results in something like this:

```
ARM_CLIENT_ID = ""
ARM_CLIENT_SECRET = ""
ARM_ENVIRONMENT = ""
ARM_LOCATION = ""
ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID = ""
ARM_TENANT_ID = ""
expressroute_settings = ""
firewall_settings = ""
peering_settings = ""
vnet_transit_object = ""
vnet_shared_services_object = ""
logging_settings = ""
```

NOTE; the two extra blank lines at the end, which is caused by my new variable array that I cannot get working.

(I understand I did state in my original question in the link above that I want to not include `ARM_`, which is still the case , but in the effort for efficient testing I have not included this in my current AWK program)

I'm trying to expand upon this idea so I can create a variable array called `myarr` and add the values from variable `string` if they are found in the file. Then in the `END` block I am able to print them out as a list.

Why do I want to print them out? So I can append some text to it, much like I have done with `varname` printing.

**EDIT**: to clarify how I would like it to output, I have created this dummy text file. I want output the values in the string to the END block (AFTER everything has been processed), hopefully by variable array (if that's the right thing to do?)
[image]

Comment: So you just want to stop the blank lines printing in the END block?

Comment: @RamanSailopal; hopefully my edit with the picture clarifies how I would like the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are having is with the lack of `{` and `}` around the `if` statements and the `for` loops:

```
BEGIN {
  string = "route_tables,global_settings"
  regex = "[,]"
  n = split ( string, arr, regex )
}
{ 
  gsub("\"", "")
}
/^variable/ {
  varname = $2
  printme = 1
}
{
  for ( i=1; i<=n; i++ ) {
    if ( $2 ~ arr[i] ) {
      printme = 0
      myarr[i] = $2
    }
  }
}
/variable/,/^}/ {
  if ( $0 ~ "default" )
     printme = 0
     next
}
printme {
  printf varname " = \"\"\n"
  printme = 0
}
END        {
  for ( x=1; x<=n; x++ ) {
    print myarr[x]
  }
}
```

```
ARM_CLIENT_ID = ""
ARM_CLIENT_SECRET = ""
ARM_ENVIRONMENT = ""
ARM_LOCATION = ""
ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID = ""
ARM_TENANT_ID = ""
expressroute_settings = ""
firewall_settings = ""
peering_settings = ""
vnet_transit_object = ""
vnet_shared_services_object = ""
logging_settings = ""
route_tables
global_settings
```

Comment: Would be easier to read if you tidied-up these indents to make it all 2 or 4 spaces.